# NFC disable/enable foreground dispatching at will

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

can we disable/enable foreground dispatching at will. onresume/onpause will help us enable and disable when the activity comes back to focus and out of focus respectively.

is there a possibility to enable and then disable the foreground dispatching.

even tried to use 
IntentFilter writeTagFilters2[]= new IntentFilter[] {  };
adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters2, null);

to give no intents to react

but it gives an error saying

Foreground dispatch can only be enabled when your activity is resumed.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you should be using [`disableForegroundDispatch(Activity)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#disableForegroundDispatch%28android.app.Activity%29) in order to remove the registration for the callback.

From the documentation for [`enableForegroundDispatch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableForegroundDispatch%28android.app.Activity,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.content.IntentFilter%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%5B%5D%29):

> This method must be called from the main thread, and only when the
>   activity is in the foreground (resumed). Also, activities must call
>   disableForegroundDispatch(Activity) before the completion of their
>   onPause() callback to disable foreground dispatch after it has been
>   enabled.

So provided your enable and disable calls reside between the `onResume()` and `onPause()` callbacks in the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html), you can call them whenever.

Regarding your error, that code must be outside of the resume/pause events. Is it in your `onCreate()` method by any chance?